# Cheerio web scraping ul > li attribute

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, request, cheerio

I want to scrape the "data-price" from this url, but it is coming back undefined. Any ideas?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9gei.png

```js
async function variant() {
    const response = await axios("https://extrabutterny.com/collections/release-draws/products/nike-sb-dunk-low-pro-blue-fury-bq6817-400?variant=31800767021104");   
    console.log("response: ", response);
    const html = await response.data;
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const id = $(".DrawApp-SizeChartList > li").attr("data-price");
    console.log(id);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When the HTML is returned by the backend, there is no List item in the class you are looking for. Here's how it looks:

```
<ul class="DrawApp-SizeChartList">
</ul>
```

There is no list item. That's the reason the `id` is `undefined`. The JavaScript runs in the browser and populates the list.

The good thing is you don't need to run a browser/puppeteer to get the price. The website makes a query to backend to get the details about the product.

Here's the url: 
https://eb-draw.herokuapp.com/draws/4482352611376

You'll see price here:

```
"variants": [
  {
    "id": 16793,
    "draw_id": 1764,
    "variant_id": "31800767021104",
    "variant_label": "8",
    "variant_price": "100.00",
    "winner_count": 3,
    "winners_left": 3,
    "current_entries": 0,
    "created_at": "2020-03-27 21:19:14",
    "updated_at": "2020-03-27 21:19:14"
  },
  ...
]
```

But where do you get the id for the product?
It's here:

```
$(".js-price-preview").attr("data-product-id")
// "4482352611376"
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you do a request, the website returns some code which will processed by your browser. Some websites return javascript code which will build the page. It's your case. The website is returning some code which need a browser to process the java script and then build the HTML.
I don't know if axios can do that, but what you need is a **headless browser**. I suggest you [Puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer).
A good tutorial [here](https://justmarkup.com/articles/2019-01-04-using-puppeteer-to-crawl-pages-and-save-them-as-markdown-files/).

Answer (score 0):

I know you accepted an answer already but if you use https://github.com/whatsdis/web-scraping-language

then you can write WSL which can render javascript pages as well and you can use Xpath:

```
GOTO https://extrabutterny.com/collections/release-draws/products/nike-sb-dunk-low-pro-blue-fury-bq6817-400?variant=31800767021104

EXTRACT {'price':'*[@class="DrawApp-SizeChartList"]/li/@data-price'}
```